# Sum of independently distributed exponential random variables

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

I got two independently distributed exponential random variables $X$, $Y$ with distribution $e^{\lambda}$.

How do we prove that the conditional distribution $X \vert U$ is a uniform distribution $U(0,u)$, i.e.
$$f_{X \vert U = u} \sim U(0,u) $$

Comment: The conditional distribution of _what_?

Comment: I think you mean the conditional distribution of $X$ (or $Y$) given $X+Y=U$.

Comment: ... and "with rate parameter $\lambda$", not "with distribution $e^\lambda$".

Comment: "I want to show that..." Nice to know. And what is your question?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I wouldn't have figured out what the OP meant if you didn't comment what you said.

Comment: @IchVerloren I have edited your question.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Bayes Theorem, we have 
$$f(x|u)=\frac{f_U(u|x)\,f_X(x)}{f_U(u)}=\frac{e^{-\lambda(u-x) } e^{-\lambda x}}{u e^{(-\lambda u)}}$$
Note that $U = X + Y $ is an Erlang random variable with parameters $(2,\lambda)$. This gives us 
$$f(x \vert u) = \frac{1}{u} \delta(x \leq u)$$
where $\delta(x < u) = 1$ if $x < u$ else it is zero. This is so because the exponential distribution $f_U(u|x)$ is defined for $ u > x$, else it is zero. Consequently, we will have $$X \vert U \sim U(0,u)$$
So you must be asking for $X \vert U$ as @Robert Israel indicates. Honestly, I wouldn't have figured it out without that comment.